ClosedXML and System.Memory Error in .NET 8: Anyone Solved This?
I’m migrating a project from .NET 4.8 to .NET 8. The ClosedXML library is compatible with .NET 8, but I’m encountering an error when using the XLWorkbook class. Despite installing System.Memory, the error still occurs, as shown in the image below. Has anyone experienced this issue or found a fix? Thanks in advance for any help!

I attempted to install and reference System.Memory in my .NET 8 project, expecting this to resolve the error thrown by ClosedXML when using the XLWorkbook class. Given that System.Memory is supposed to address compatibility issues related to memory management across versions, I anticipated that adding this package would allow ClosedXML to function as it did in .NET 4.8 without error
